# Rebuilding git branch after a faulty merge (respecting merge commits)

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a classic situation: I merged a `dev` branch into `master`, then realised I made a mistake and reverted the merge. Then added a fix into `dev` and want to merge it again. Of course, I cannot merge it directly, since, from git's point of view, it was already merged.

#### Classic solution

Revert the revert commit, apply your fix. Move on.

- **Pros**: simple.
- **Cons**: history is spoiled. It is very hard to blame deeper than this revert of the revert.

#### What I want

I want to rebuild the `dev` branch from scratch, and merge it again. Should be easily done with `git rebase --force-rebase`, according to the books. But the branch history was not so simple, and contained a number of merges, including merges from `master`. I want to respect these.

Let's have an example already:

```
                                     master|
                                           v
-*------------X-----Y---------*-----*----M-W
  \          /       \         \   /    /
   \        /         \         -*-    /
    \      /  -D-      G--H--         /
     \    /  /   \    /      \       /
      A--B--C-----E--F--------I-----J
                                    ^
                                    |dev
```

The faulty merge is `M`. Its revert is `W`. I assume that commits on `dev` up to `B` are ok, since `B` was merged into `master` as `X`. I want to rebuild the branch starting from `B` with exactly the same topology. See the tree below. New commits are marked with the prime. You can see how commits `C..J` were rebased to `C'..J'`. Correspondingly, `dev` is rebased to `dev'`. Other commits did not change.

```
                                dev'|
                                    v
            C'----E'-F'-------I'----J'
           / \   /    \      /        
          |   -D'      G'-H'-           
          |           /                    |master
          |          /                     v
-*--------+---X-----Y---------*-----*----M-W
  \       |  /       \         \   /    /
   \      | /         \         -*-    /
    \     |/  -D-      G--H--         /
     \    /  /   \    /      \       /
      A--B--C-----E--F--------I-----J
                                    ^
                                    |dev
```

Then I'll apply my fix `K` and merge this new branch to `master`:

```
                                dev'|
                                    v
            C'----E'-F'-------I'----J'--K
           / \   /    \      /           \
          |   -D'      G'-H'-             \
          |           /                    \ |master
          |          /                      \v
-*--------+---X-----Y---------*-----*----M-W-M2
  \       |  /       \         \   /    /
   \      | /         \         -*-    /
    \     |/  -D-      G--H--         /
     \    /  /   \    /      \       /
      A--B--C-----E--F--------I-----J
                                    ^
                                    |dev
```

- **Pros**: good history.
- **Cons**: I don't know how to do this.

Ok, seems like `rebase` has an option for this, and it is called `--rebase-merges`. But it does not do what I want. It rebases all commits, **that are ancestors of `dev` and descendants of `B`**. Which includes commits `X` and `Y`. Which are on `master` already, why would I want them? (Actually, it also brings some other commits from the more ancient history, and I don't understand why yet, but it's not the point here).

Instead, I want to bring commits, **that are ancestors of `dev` but not `master`** (considering `master` before the faulty merge of course). Sounds really easy to me. Yet I don't understand how to do it, except by manually constructing this difference of commits and somehow cherry-picking them by hand, carefully preserving parents.

So, how do I rebuild my branch, containing *only work done on my branch* and respecting merge commits?

**PS** We cannot simply reset `master` to `M^`, that would be too easy.

Comment: You talk about *rebuild*-ing a branch, but what you mean by that is unclear (and I think led to some confusing regarding the helpfulness of my answer). I answered your last question (*how do I recreate my branch*). Can you [edit] and clarify what *rebuild*-ing means to you? Your question mentions rebasing, which is typically to change history...

Comment: Ok, I see where your confusion comes from. Sorry for that. I changed "recreate" to "rebuild" and added some clarifications about commits with primes (like `C'`). Hope this helps

Comment: Forgive me, but I still don't understand the goal here: why must we create new `C'` via a rebase? Are they in need of editing (faulty commits)? Rebuild still doesn't mean to me what it does to you, I suspect: do you want the same topology but with different commits, or are the same commits acceptable to you (you'll still apply the fix in K, so why change the old commits?)? Finally, why do you say is difficult to blame deeper than the reverts? `git-blame` has always worked well for me.

Comment: "do you want the same topology but with different commits" - yes. "are the same commits acceptable to you" - no, because these commits are already merged to master and reverted. Merging them again would be a no-op to git. "why do you say is difficult to blame deeper than the reverts" - well, I had bad experience with it. But I will need to check how this parituclar case is handled. Not 100% sure. My goal here is to "repeat the merge". But it cannot be done with same commits, since they are already merged. Thus, I want to rebuild a new branch, which is just like the previous branch.

Comment: I would encourage you to check out https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt, which explains how to do what you want.

Comment: Yeap, went through this stuff many years ago. Really useful reading. I'm actually trying to do exactly the same thing as at the very end of the document, but I want it to handle merges. Look for "recreated topic branch". And they use `rebase --no-ff` (which is the same thing as `rebase --force`). I added `--rebase-merges` to it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Its unclear to me that `—no-ff` is equivalent to `—force`, but im still not sure why the revert-revert is a problem. At any rate, ive given the answers i can, but maybe some one else can answer your question

Comment: Commit `M` has two parents: you drew both in your initial graph, but dropped one in your subsequent graphs. Since no commit can ever be changed, commit `M` still, always, and forever has two parents. Future merges will follow both parents to compute the merge base. That's where it all goes wrong. One other thing you *can* do is use `git replace` to tell Git to stop looking at `M` at all. Note, however, that replacement references don't get copied on normal clone operations.

Comment: If you don't want to use `git replace` (I wouldn't—it's kind of a mine field), your only other option is to remove `M` entirely. You *can* do that using `git replace` followed by `git filter-branch`. It's less mine-field-y but more painful.

Comment: Finally, yes, you can do what you're looking at doing: copy all the *other* branch's commits, so that the merge `M` doesn't really matter any more. But that's probably even more painful than using `git replace`, with or without filter-branch. In theory it should be possible in some cases with the new rebase-merges, but it might be easier to do with filter-branch and a commit-filter that changes the committer timestamp on the right set of commits. (I should probably turn these into an answer, but they're only sort of 80%-realized thoughts).

Comment: @torek "you drew both in your initial graph, but dropped one in your subsequent graphs" - my bad. I omitted it to keep the drawing compact. I added it on the drawing, hope now it is more clear.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble "Its unclear to me that —no-ff is equivalent to —force" - it's in the docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---no-ff 
"but im still not sure why the revert-revert is a problem" - I got it, but it's a different question :)

Comment: @torek "your only other option is to remove M entirely" - as I've said, I cannot reset `master`. "But that's probably even more painful than using git replace" - that's very surprizing to me! I formulated the rule and it seems very simple! And the use case seems very clear (despite the fact I failed to explain it well).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Just checked `git blame` and `git log`. No, there weren't able to follow file's history back to before the revert of the revert. The file history stops at this point, git thinks it was first introduced there. The rich history of edits done in `dev` is lost.

Comment: Did the files move? This is shocking. Have you tried the `follow` flag?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble According to the docs, "follow" is by default in the latest git versions, and there is simply no way to turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems like I found a solution:

1. `git rebase --interactive --rebase-merges B dev`
2. reword C

This produces exactly the history I want. Credits to [@mstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241453/mstrap) for the hint.

I'm not exactly sure why this works the way I want though.

Answer (score -1):

Based on https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt, I would

```
git checkout dev
$EDITOR files
git commit files -m 'Fix'
git checkout master
git revert W
git merge dev
```

The revert-revert is necessary to keep the changes when you re-merge.